# How change theme color programmatically: style, attributes android?

Tags: android, attributes, styles, themes, view

I used google but didn't find an accurate solution, for changing themes programmatically.
I want to change everything programmatically: styles, colors, attributes etc., without using style.xml, theme.xml or any other xml file.
I have searched, but styles are defined in an xml file like that [Using Themes in Android Applications](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html)

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: No, simply i have create multiple drawables with multiple colors, and change the background on theme button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but if someone's still looking for a solution, checkout the [GreenMatter](https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter) library for the Material theme, or for the Holo theme [holoaccent](https://github.com/negusoft/holoaccent).